# sed is appending next line after replacing first line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` in following properties files code using `sed` / `awk`

```
jdbc.connection.driver_class=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
jdbc.connection.username=USERNAME
jdbc.connection.password=PASSWORD

jdbc.minPoolSize=1
jdbc.maxPoolSize=15
```

I tried it using the following script

```
sed -i -e "s/^${JDBC_USER_KEY}=.*/${JDBC_USER_KEY}=${DATABASE_USER_NAME}/" \
       -e "s/^${JDBC_PASSWORD_KEY}=.*/${JDBC_PASSWORD_KEY}=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}/"  database.properties
```

Where :

```
JDBC_USER_KEY=jdbc.connection.username
DATABASE_USER_NAME=TEST
JDBC_PASSWORD_KEY=jdbc.connection.password
DATABASE_PASSWORD=TEST
```

But, the output is :

```
jdbc.connection.driver_class=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
jdbc.connection.username=TESTjdbc.connection.password=TEST

jdbc.minPoolSize=1
jdbc.maxPoolSize=15
```

The value has been replaced but the next line "jdbc.connection.password=TEST" has been appeneded with previous line.

I searched a lot on Google but did not find any solution/s.

I also tried `awk` (See the following):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="=";OFS="=" } {if($1==pname) $2=newval; print $0,"\n"}' pname="$property_name" newval="$new_value" $ARTIFACTS_HOME/properties/$1 >> $ARTIFACTS_HOME/properties/test.properties
```

Where `$property_name` is `jdbc.connection.username` and `$new_value` is `TEST`.

Please help!

Comment: Works fine for me.  You might get problems like this if you had DOS/Windows line endings on your database.properties file because those `sed` substitutions will remove the DOS-style carriage return character.

Comment: the sed works also nicely for me ... except i have had to group the two -e in one `sed -i -e "s/^${JDBC_USER_KEY}=.*/${JDBC_USER_KEY}=${DATABASE_USER_NAME}/;s/^${JDBC_PASSWORD_KEY}=.*/${JDBC_PASSWORD_KEY}=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}/" database.properties`

Comment: To resolve John1024's suggested cause, just add `dos2unix` to the pipeline.

Comment: See what the `file` command says about the file.  `file database.properties`